# When my iframe loads, two scrolls are coming, if I set scrolling to no for iframe, it will not show complete content of website

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have main site A and i am loading site B in iframe under site A. but when site B loads under site A. It is showing two scrolls. when i remove scroll by no scrolling, its content become static and fixed sized. altought site B has much content to show.

I tried

```
    <iframe src="http://siteB.com" style="border: 0; position:absolute; 
top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%">
```

I also tried javascript code, but its not working in my case.

```
<iframe id='myFrame' 
 frameborder=0 scrolling=no width=100%  
src="..."
   onload='adjustMyFrameSize();'> 
</iframe> 



   <script>
function adjustMyFrameHeight()
  {
      var frame = getElement("myFrame");
       var frameDoc = getIFrameDocument("myFrame");
       frame.height = frameDoc.body.offsetHeight;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

get your iframe in variable

```
 var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('ppm-externalapp-iframe');
```

then set property

```
 ele[0].style.height = '200px';
```

Comment: i dont want to give it fix height.

Comment: i put it just for example

Comment: you can add it dynamically using js

Comment: as you used in your question `frameDoc.body.offsetHeight`